# Extended ASCII in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, extended-ascii

I'm trying to create an inspiration app, which displays random words. it works for alpha characters, but when a word has characters like `öäü` or `ß` in them, it just displays random gibberish.

Wanted Text: `Rindfleischverpackungsetikettierungsgerät`

Text displayed: `RindfleischverpackungsetikettierungsgerÃŸt`

Another Example:

[image: screenshot showing characters]

Here is my code for it (still very basic and functional)

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint

class ButtonBlock(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.button = []
        self.button_val = tk.IntVar()
        entry = tk.Entry()
        entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
        entry.bind('<Return>', self.onEnter)
    def onEnter(self, event):
        entry = event.widget
        num = int(entry.get())
        for button in self.button:
            button.destroy()
        for i in range(1, num+1):
            leine = randint(1, 1908815)
            print(leinen[leine])
            self.button.append(tk.Label(
                self.master, text=leinen[leine]))
            self.button[-1].grid(sticky='WENS', row=i, column=2, padx=1, pady=1)
    def onSelect(self):
        print(self.button_val.get())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    deutsch = open("WORT.txt", "r")
    leinen = deutsch.readlines()

    root = tk.Tk()
    ButtonBlock(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Is there any way to allow tkinter to render the characters `öäüß` properly? (BTW `WORT.txt` is just a word list)

Comment: `tkinter` can display 8-bit Unicode which should include all the characters you want and Python 3 assumes all strings use that encoding (known as "utf-8". Your text file may be using some other encode. Try specifying different ones when calling `open()`: i.e. `open("WORT.txt", "r", encoding="latin1")`.

Comment: P.S. You should [edit] your question and include a short same of the input file in it as **text**, not an image.

Comment: @martineau i added an Example in text form
Your Response really helped me :)

Comment: Actually I meant more than one line of the text file. Regardless, I can't use the code in your question because of getting an `IndexError: list index out of range` for the `leinen[leine]`. This is because the value of `leine` is often way too big due to the `leine = randint(1, 1908815)`. None of that has anything to do with  the problem. Please provide a [mre] *which means take everything out unrelated to the problem*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the extended ASCII characters in the text file, specify the encoding when you `open` the file like this:

```
deutsch = open("WORT.txt", "r", encoding="latin1")
```

This needs to be done because if `encoding` is not specified the default used is platform dependent (and apparently not the `"latin1"` needed
on your system). See the documentation for the built-in [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function.

Comment: Note that the encoding could also be other things like `"iso-8859-1"` or Windows' `"cp1252"`, both of which include those same characters — this ideal thing to do would be to find out the actual encoding of text file from its creator.